# How to get product names by attribute value?

Tags: magento2, attributes, products

I have custom dropdown attribute with yes and no values.
I want to get only those product names which have attribute value yes.
I am trying to avoid using object manager directly, so I need to accomplish this using dependencies.
Any ideas?

Comment: on list page Or somewhere else ?

Answer (score 3):

> Using object manager

```
    $productcollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection')
                                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                                        ->addAttributeToSelect('custom_attribute','1');
```

use `echo '<pre>';print_r($productcollection->getData());` to get product datas

> Using constructor method

```
protected $_productRepository;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
) {
    $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
}

punblic function getProductCollection(){
       $productcollection = $this->_productRepository->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('custom_attribute','1');
       return $productcollection;
}
```

use `echo '<pre>';print_r($this->getProductCollection()->getData());` to get product datas